# How to fix python pytorch library version problem?

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

Warning (from warnings module):
File "C:\Users\mesut\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\optim\lr_scheduler.py", line 134
"https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#how-to-adjust-learning-rate", UserWarning)
UserWarning: Detected call of `lr_scheduler.step()` before `optimizer.step()`. In PyTorch 1.1.0 and later, you should call them in the opposite order: `optimizer.step()` before `lr_scheduler.step()`.  Failure to do this will result in PyTorch skipping the first value of the learning rate schedule. See more details at https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#how-to-adjust-learning-rate

Comment: What is the problem? Have you read the link in the warning?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have a version problem.

The warning usually takes place when you change your learning rate before updating the actual model weights.

In latest version of Pytorch which you seem to have, the code outputs a warning because it does not make sense to change the learning rate before a single optimization has taken place on the model. Instead just initialize your learning rates differently in the first place.

As a result, the warning says Pytorch skips the first value of the lr scheduler and just first optimizes. However, this is redudant and not a good implementation of code hence the warning.

Therefore, I advise you to get rid of this error to first run

```
optimizer.step()
lr_scheduler.step()
```

Instead of the other way which you seem to have it.

Sarthak Jain